# PHP Compile Error trying to get mcrypt, Mac OSx 10.6

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, mcrypt

I  and working on setting up a LAMP stack on a new Mac Mini to use as a web server. I am using the bundled PHP version 5.3.3 and Apache 2.2.15.

I have gotten phpMyAdmin working and connect to my mysql installation but I get a "Cannot load mcrypt extension. I did this tutorial - http://michaelgracie.com/2009/09/23/plugging-mcrypt-into-php-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-10.6.1/ - to get mcrypt installed and phpinfo() shows mcrypt is installed as per the screenshot at the end.

But im still getting the mcrypt extension not loaded warning. How can I get rid of this. This server is eventually going to be used for production and I would like it to be secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace extension=mcrypt.so from the tutorial with extension=the/full/path/to/mcrypt.so seems to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

You may have built mcrypt as i386. Check this with the file command (`file mcrypt.so`).

Your new Mac mini is 64-bit. Try building mcrypt as x86_64. You could try hacking the Makefile or setting `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"`.

Comment: I ended up fixing this my adding to full path to mcrypt.so to the php.ini file instead of just extension=mcrypt.so. Thanks for taking a stab at it Paul.